# problem in c there's an empty character constant error

Tags: c

I've got a problem in C. The console says that there's an empty character constant. It's a little program to know how much books have a person. Here is the code :

```
int main ()
{
    int nb_books;
    printf("How much books have you got?");
    scanf("%d",&nb_books);
    printf("You have %d book%c!\n",nb_books, (nb_books==0||nb_books==1)?'':'s');
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is with `%c`, I'd like to put a `s` when there are several books. That's all!

Comment: `''` is not a valid construct in C. A string can be `""`, but a char must always be equal to one character.

Answer (score 5):

There is no "empty" character, so `''` is illegal.

Use `%s` instead of `%c`, then you can use a 0-length string, eg:

```
printf("You have %d book%s!\n", nb_books, (nb_books==1)?"":"s");
```

(you should be outputting `s` for "0 book**s**")

Comment: For the code golfers,  `"s" + (nb_books == 1)`

Answer (score -3):

Try this instead:

```
int main ()
{
    int nb_books;
    printf("How much books have you got?");
    scanf("%d",&nb_books);
    printf("You have %d book%c!\n",nb_books, (nb_books==0||nb_books==1) ? NULL : 's');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At _best_ this will attempt to print a _null chracter_.  Better to print no suffix at all.